# Pine script resolution

Tags: pine-script

```
plot(imi, color=color.new(165, 42, 42), linewidth=2, title="Intraday Momentum Index")
```

I am getting error as

> "Too much arguments"

This code defines two horizontal lines (hline1 and hline2) and fills the area between them with a specific color.

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_color.new

Comment: color.new accepts 2 arguments, you passed 3

Answer (score 0):

use color.rgb:

```
plot(imi, color=color.rgb(165, 42, 42), linewidth=2, title="Intraday Momentum Index")
```